# TortoiseSvn plug-in/integration with Flash CS5?

Tags: flash, tortoisesvn, flash-cs5

I used TortoiseSvn for source control in my flash projects. I recently upgraded from cs3 to cs5 and I like the new project window but was curious if anyone knows of an svn plug-in that would work inside the project window? My google-foo has failed me in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I would chime in since nobody has answered this yet.  If there is an SVN plugin for CS4/CS5, I don't know of it.. however, Flash Builder is essentially Eclipse, and that has plenty of source control plugins (i.e. Subclipse).

This is a bit more of a tangent, but since it's Flash/SVN related, might be of interest:
http://dougmccune.com/blog/2009/01/20/accessing-svn-repositories-with-actionscript/

The creation of an SVN plugin is probably possible, but chances are it will be much easier to just continue using TortoiseSVN unless you move to Flash Builder.